# Variable passing to find function in rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables

I am new to Rails. I have following construction. Mainmenu in my project has many submenus. In defining @submenu is everything ok, but in finding @mainmenu not. The output is: Couldn't find Mainmenu without an ID

```
@submenu = Submenu.find(params[:submenu_id])
@mainmenu = Mainmenu.find(params[:id => @submenu.mainmenu_id])
```

How can i define @mainmenu so it is submenu`s upperclass?

I have Rails 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails allows you to retrieve relations just like that :

```
@mainmenu = @submenu.mainmenu
```

But if you wanted (for some obscure reason or in an other context), to retrieve the menu like you did before, you should do :

```
@mainmenu = Mainmenu.find_by_id(@submenu.mainmenu_id)
```

You might want to read this : [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) in order to know how to appropriately do SQL queries with Active Record.